# Visual basic : Calculate Average function returning infinity

Tags: vb.net, function, visual-studio-2012

I am supposed to calculate the average number of words and then convert them into a percentage, however they are displaying infinity. The code I am using is below .

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Structure advertisements
        Public name As String
        Public words As Integer
        Public font() As fonts
        Public mostLegible As String
    End Structure

    Private Structure fonts
        Public name As String
        Public NoWords() As Integer
        Public aveWords As Double
        Public percent As Double
    End Structure

    Private noAdverts As Integer
    Private noFonts As Integer
    Private noReaders As Integer
    Private advert() As advertisements

    Private Sub GridPlacement(ByVal r As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal t As String)
        grdDisplay.Row = r
        grdDisplay.Col = c
        grdDisplay.Text = t
    End Sub

    Private Sub gridAndArraySettings()
        Dim x, y As Integer
        ReDim advert(noAdverts)
        For x = 1 To noAdverts
            ReDim advert(x).font(noFonts)
            For y = 1 To noFonts
                ReDim advert(x).font(y).NoWords(noReaders)
                'GridPlacement(0, y, "font " & CStr(y))
            Next
        Next
        grdDisplay.Cols = noFonts + 2
        grdDisplay.Rows = noAdverts + 1

        GridPlacement(0, 0, "Name of advert")


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        noAdverts = CInt(txtadverts.Text)
        noReaders = CInt(txtReaders.Text)
        noFonts = CInt(txtFonts.Text)

        gridAndArraySettings()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInput.Click
        Dim x, y, z As Integer
        Dim total(,) As Integer
        ReDim total(noAdverts, noFonts)

        For x = 1 To noAdverts
            advert(x).name = InputBox("please enter the name of advert " & CStr(x))
            advert(x).words = CInt(InputBox("please enter the number of words for " & advert(x).name))
            GridPlacement(x, 0, advert(x).name)
            For y = 1 To noFonts
                advert(x).font(y).name = InputBox("please enter the name of font " & CStr(y) & " Used in advert " & CStr(x))
                For z = 1 To noReaders
                    advert(x).font(y).NoWords(z) = CInt(InputBox("please enter the number of words understood by reader " & CStr(z) & " for font " & advert(x).font(y).name & " in advert " & advert(x).name))
                    total(x, y) += advert(x).font(y).NoWords(z)
                Next
                advert(x).font(y).aveWords = calcAve(total(x, y))
                advert(x).font(y).percent = advert(x).font(y).aveWords * 100

                GridPlacement(x, y, CStr(advert(x).font(y).aveWords)) 'Format(advert(x).font(y).percent, "###%")
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function calcAve(ByVal elements As Integer) As Double
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim placeholder As Double = 1

        Select Case elements
            Case Is > 0
                For x = 1 To noAdverts
                    For y = 1 To noFonts
                        advert(x).font(y).aveWords = (elements / noReaders) / advert(x).words
                        placeholder = advert(x).font(y).aveWords
                        MsgBox(CStr(placeholder))
                    Next y
                Next x
            Case Is = 0
                MsgBox("There is incorrect values ")
        End Select
        Return placeholder
    End Function
End Class
```

The textboxes are called `txtadverts`, `txtfonts` and `txtreaders`

The button `btnsubmit` gets the input from the textboxes and stores them in variables. `btninput` allows input from user.

`GrdDisplay` is a custom extension used by my university which is a 2D grid used to diplay values.

Comment: Where does `noReaders` come from?

Comment: Fairly certain you want this tagged as VB.net, not VBA.

Comment: it comes from a text box called txtreaders

Comment: There's probably a division by 0 somewhere as division by 0 for Double will yield +Infinity or -Infinity (depending of operands sign) but without a _[minimal, complete and verifiable exemple](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ it'll be hard to say more.

Comment: don't know if this helps, i added an message box and with the message box , it displays the correct answer twice and then infinity twice thereafter

Comment: @Zubair786 no it's not really helping ; we can't execute your code ... so adding a MsgBox we can't use won't help.